# Java abstract class inheritance by declaring new methods

Tags: java, methods, abstract, instantiation

In my android project I have an abstract class Request

```
package Managers;

import java.util.HashMap;

public abstract class Request {
    public interface Completion {
        void execute(HashMap<String, Object> result);
    }

    protected Completion completion;
    protected HashMap<String, Object> requestResult;

    public void setCompletion(Completion newCompletion) {
        completion = newCompletion;
        if (requestResult != null) {
            completion.execute(requestResult);
            requestResult = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my RequestsManager Class I have instantiated it like so

```
public static Request numberAvailabilityCheck = new Request() {
    public String isSuccess = "isSuccess";
    public String result = "result";

    public void sendRequest(String number) {
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                requestResult.put(isSuccess, true);
                requestResult.put(result, true);
                if (completion != null) {
                    completion.execute(requestResult);
                    requestResult = null;
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    };
};
```

In my MainFragment class I need to use numberAvailabilityCheck like so

```
private View.OnClickListener checkEventListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RequestsManager.numberAvailabilityCheck.setCompletion(numberAvailabilityCheckCompletion);
        ViewRelatedUtils.closeKeyboard(getActivity());
        isProcessingCheckNumber = true;
        showProcessing();
        RequestsManager.numberAvailabilityCheck.sendRequest(numberField.getText());
    }
};
```

But compiler does not see RequestsManager.numberAvailabilityCheck.sendRequest method in MainFragment. Why compiler doesn't see it? What understands compiler when I declare public method sendRequest in RequestsManager like so? And how can I make a compiler see it?

Comment: You cant create a new method signature in an anonymous class and expect any other code to understand that this new signature exists. If you want the underlying class which expects some `T` such that `T extends Request`, then it can only reasonably expect to be able to call methods which exist in the base class `Request`

Comment: @flakes What understands compiler when I declare public method sendRequest in RequestsManager like so?

Comment: `numAvailabilityCheck` is a variable of type `Request`, and the type `Request` does not have that method. If you make the variable of some named subtype of `Request` that declares that method, then you can call it.

Comment: See the comment above by @khelwood OP. If you declare the variable as the type `Request`, then you can only call methods defined in `Request`. If you want the non-defined method to be callable, then declare it as an abstract method in `Request ` which must be defined by any concrete or anonymous class which extends `Request`.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear and to outline a possible solution based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for describing me why compiler doesn't see a method. I have found a solution that, I think, is the most comfort solution for me. In RequestsManager I have declared a public class NumberAvailabilityCheck that extends Request and public static member of that class numberAvailabilityCheck.

```
public static class NumberAvailabilityCheck extends Request {
    public String isSuccess = "isSuccess";
    public String result = "result";

    public void sendRequest(String number) {
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                requestResult.put(isSuccess, true);
                requestResult.put(result, true);
                if (completion != null) {
                    completion.execute(requestResult);
                    requestResult = null;
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    };
};
public static NumberAvailabilityCheck numberAvailabilityCheck = new NumberAvailabilityCheck();
```

Note that NumberAvailabilityCheck cannot be declared as private.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your code can invoke the method setCompletion() without a problem!

That method is defined on you base class. The other method is only defined within the scope of your anonymous inner class instantiation! Therefore the compiler doesn't "see" it and prevents you from invoking it!

Please note: if you could somehow turn that field into a local variable declared without a type (by using the new var keyword of Java 10), your code would work: as the compiler can infere the fact that you added that method. But by declaring that object to be of type Request, the compiler can only tell you that this method does not exist.

But using var is not a good approach, instead the solution could be: add an abstract method for sendRequest() to your class Request! If that isn't possible, then consider to not use a single abstract base class, why not have additional abstract classes that extend your base class, each one providing a slightly different send method.

Comment: What understands compiler when I declare public method sendRequest in RequestsManager like so? And there is one problem related with abstract method sendRequest(). In different cases this method gets different combinations of arguments.